# How to force download of file from ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

This is my web-api code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostFileAsAttachment()
    {
        string path = "D:\\heroAccent.png";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {

            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "xx.png";
            return result;
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
```

And how to Code the Client side(view) to force a download file to me(like auto download mode(open、save as) can pop up...)

Comment: Do you mean like you want to show Open, Save As popup before the file is downloaded?

Comment: Yes..I want to use jquery ajax method ,and how to do it?

Comment: but after HttpResponseMessage return back

Comment: You can either navigate to this download url with `window.location`, or open a new window with `window.open()` from javascript. You can't actually download a file with ajax.

Comment: I am facing the exact problem. Did you get a solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated, you can't trigger 'the open/save as' dialog from ajax.

If you want to preserve the current page content while downloading the file you could add a hidden iframe somewhere in your page and have your download link do some JS behind the scenes to set the *src* attribute of said iframe to the appropriate location.

```
$('iframeSelector').attr('src', downloadLinkLocation)
```

I've tested this with an action returning a *FileContentResult* but if you set *ContentDisposition* in the response headers, as you do, I see no reason why it wouldn't work with the WebAPI method.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ActionResult type that is available for files is FileResult
If the content you want to transfer is stored within a disk file, you can use the FilePathResult object. If your content is available through a stream you use FileStreamResult and you opt for FileContentResult if you have it available as a byte array. All these objects derive from FileResult and differ from one another only in the way that they write out data to the response stream.

ex: for PDF

```
public FileResult Export()
{
var output = new MemoryStream();
    :
    return File(output.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "MyFile.pdf");
}
```

Please find the link below to know how to call the action method using Ajax Jquery

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/11/ajax-calls-to-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-using-jquery/

You could refer this articles which could give you some idea on the FileResult

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=807

Comment: I don't want to use mvc action,I just want to call the web-api method directly by client side,like:                                                          $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: 'http://localhost/WebAPITest/api/MyAPI'
                        , type: "post"
                        , contentType: "application/json"
                        , data: ''
                        , success:
                        function (retData) {

                            *****
                        }

Comment: I just don't know how to process the retdata param from the ajax success function to popup me a download